# Convert Array to querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, model-view-controller

I have a page for filters, I get all filters and set to a array.

```
$('.content-items:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (name.slice(-2) === '[]') {
        name = $(this).attr('name').slice(0, -2);
        if (typeof params[name] === 'undefined') {
            params[name] = [];
        }
        params[name].push($(this).val());
    } else {
        params[name] = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

I have a Array of filters, like `cat[2]{"7","3"},fac[1]{"1"}`.

I want to convert it to Query string, and change url.

> /product?cat[0]=7&cat[1]=3&fac[0]=1

Comment: Is this a string - `cat[2]{"7","3"},fac[1]{"1"}`?

Comment: No, I think that's console representation @randomSoul - `cat` has length `2`, and contains `["7", "3"]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `join` after creating a temporary object to store the names of the arrays:

```js
const cat = ["7", "3"];
const fac = ["1"];
const obj = { cat, fac };
const res = "/product?" + Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => v.map((e, i) => `${k}[${i}]=${e}`).join("&")).join("&");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your checkboxes are inside a form, you can just call `var urlString = $("{selector-for-Form}").serialize()` .This will save you a lot of hassle, [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
 is the Api documentation for it.